# Cumulative hotfix for Sitecore XP 10.2 - Container

Tags: container

Need your help on the below,

**Issue:** Sitecore CM - Unable to access content Editor - Need to install the Cumulative hotfix  (Sitecore XP 10.2.0).

**Description:**  In one of our Sitecore applications, we are using Sitecore XP 10.2 (Headless, Containers) and are unable to load the Content Editor suddenly and below are the exception details,

As a temporary fix, we have restarted the PODs to make them workable. But seems this is a known issue in the Sitecore (https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001823) and we are supposed to install this hotfix as a permanent fix.

```
ERROR [Sitecore.Web.HttpModule] Application error.
Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.PrefetchData.AddChildId(ID childId)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.PrefetchData.AddChildrenForEmptyDefinition(IDList list)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.GetChildIDs(ItemDefinition itemDefinition, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.CompositeDataProvider.<DoGetChildIDs>d__94.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.Common.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 sequence, Action`1 action)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.CompositeDataProvider.GetChildIDs(ItemDefinition itemDefinition, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.GetChildIDs(ItemDefinition item, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetChildIDs(ID itemID)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetChildrenCommand.Execute(Item item)
   ...
```

As we are pretty new to Sitecore XP 10.2, we are unable to move forward with the hotfix provided. It would be really helpful if someone can explain how to install this hotfix in the new version (10.2.x).

**Version:** Sitecore 10.2.x (Headless, Containers)

Answer (score 1):

- The first step is to download the Sitecore pre-release or hotfix package. You can do this from the Sitecore website or by contacting Sitecore support. Save the package to a local directory on your machine.
- Check the `Sitecore 10.2.x rev. xxxxxx PRE/Documentation/Sitecore.Platform.Instructions 10.2.x rev. xxxxxx PRE.md file` that can contain specific instructions if they are required.
- You must add Dockerfile instructions for each Sitecore required server role. If you don’t have a role-specific Dockerfile, you can create a docker/build folder and create `Dockerfile` containing the required instruction to create a custom image. If you already have Dockerfile for the CM role, just update that file with the below-mentioned changes.
- To add the Dockerfile instructions for the Content Management (CM) role, on your solution, open the Sitecore runtime Dockerfile for the CM role and add the following instructions to pull the image. Make Sure, `${PARENT_IMAGE}` should be applied in the last.

```
# escape=`
 
ARG PARENT_IMAGE
# To add pre-release or delta asset image
ARG DELTA_ASSET_IMAGE
 
# add any other tooling image, like MANAGEMENT_SERVICES_IMAGE
[...]
 
FROM ${DELTA_ASSET_IMAGE} as deltaAssetImage
# Make sure Parent image or base image should be in the last
FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 
WORKDIR C:\inetpub\wwwroot
 
# Copy cm resources from pre-releae inage
COPY --from=deltaAssetImage \platform\cm \
```

- In your vanilla instance, you must be having `docker-compose.yml` file. Now to create custom images, you must create a `docker-compose.override.yml` file – that will update the Docker Compose file. If you already have `docker-compose.override.yml` file, you can update that.

To configure the custom image for the CM role in Docker Compose, add the following code to the `docker-compose.override.yml` file:

```
cm:
  image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-cm:${VERSION:-latest}
  build:
    context: ./docker/build/cm
    args:
      PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cm:${SITECORE_VERSION}
      DELTA_ASSET_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_PRE_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-assets:${DELTA_ASSET_IMAGE_VERSION}
  [...]
```

- Build the images and up the containers.

You can find more details on https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2023/03/12/apply-hotfix-to-sitecore-docker-images/